# Regex for getting the value up to last space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string value to which i want to split and preserve all the characters upto last space.

```
e.g var x="item1 item2 item3 *stopMarker" 
var y=someRegOpr(x); and y will contain only "item1 item2 item3"
```

How to do this by a Regular Expression.

Thanks

Comment: why regex?................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you use [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) instead:

```
var x = "item1 item2 item3 *stopMarker";
x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf(" "));  // "item1 item2 item3"
```

---

**UPDATE:** Hack for a single word without spaces:

```
var x = "item1";
x.substring(0, Math.max(0, x.lastIndexOf(" ")) || Infinity);  // "item1"
```

---

**UPDATE2:** All the same using regex:

```
"item1 item2 item3 *stopMarker".split(/ [^ ]*$/).pop();  // "item1 item2 item3"
```

Comment: +1 Don't see any need for a regex to be used, keep it simple.

Comment: @mns And it is many times faster than using regular expressions.

Comment: but what if it is a single word without any space,its returning blank

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = "item1 item2 item3 *stopMarker";
var ans = x.match(/(.*)\s[^\s]*/);
```

Then answer will be stored in `ans[1]`

Comment: Close, but why not simply `/[^\s]+$/`?

Answer (score 1):

this should get what you want:

```
'item1 item2 item3 *stopMarker'.split(/(.*)\s.*$/)
```

will result in

```
["", "item1 item2 item3", ""]
```

Then you'd just have to filter the `""` out manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to SPLIT the string and obtain an *array* without the *stopMarker, then this is what you want:

```
var x="item1 item2 item3 *stopMarker";
var y = x.split(" ");
y=y.splice(0, y.length-1);
```

If not, just use the .lastIndexOf solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use "followed by" expression:

```
"item1 item2 item3 *stopMarker".match( /^.*(?=\s)/i )
>> ["item1 item2 item3"]
```